# print(Mirror.DisplayStyle.CASE) for cases .Collection, .Dictionary and .Set produce legacy (Swift 1.2) names, when used in playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground, mirror

### Question

- Is the `Mirror.DisplayStyle` "legacy printing" behaviour described below expected? And if so, why would we possibly want to expose legacy/internal case names when printing these cases in a playground (but not for e.g. running an XCode project)?

I am running Swift 2.2, Xcode 7.3, in a playground.

---

***Edit addition:***

From the info given by @J.Wang in the comments below, it seems the `Mirror.DisplayStyle` extension to conformance to `CustomStringConvertible` (in the `PlaygroundLogger` module) is deprecated, w.r.t. descriptors (`.description`) for cases `Collection`, `Dictionary` and `Set`. Whether it's a bug or just very-low-priority update; a rdar has been filed here just in case:

- http://www.openradar.me/25540375

---

### Background and details

The enum `DisplayStyle` for the `Mirror` structure has public interface as follows

```
public enum DisplayStyle {
    case Struct
    case Class
    case Enum
    case Tuple
    case Optional
    case Collection
    case Dictionary
    case Set
}
```

If I print these cases (***in a playground***), I'd expect the respective case name to be printed. However, for cases `Collection`, `Dictionary` and `Set`, we get [the `MirrorDisposition` legacy case names](http://swiftdoc.org/v1.2/type/MirrorDisposition/) `IndexContainer`, `KeyContainer` and `MembershipContainer`, respectively.

```
print(Mirror.DisplayStyle.Class)       // Class
print(Mirror.DisplayStyle.Collection)  // IndexContainer      <---
print(Mirror.DisplayStyle.Dictionary)  // KeyContainer        <---
print(Mirror.DisplayStyle.Enum)        // Enum
print(Mirror.DisplayStyle.Optional)    // Optional
print(Mirror.DisplayStyle.Set)         // MembershipContainer <---
print(Mirror.DisplayStyle.Struct)      // Struct
print(Mirror.DisplayStyle.Tuple)       // Tuple
```

I.e., the same as when printing the cases for the internal (undocumented?) `_MirrorDisposition` enum

```
print(_MirrorDisposition.IndexContainer)      // IndexContainer
print(_MirrorDisposition.KeyContainer)        // KeyContainer
print(_MirrorDisposition.MembershipContainer) // MembershipContainer
```

The above "shadow case printing" is, however, not present if printing these cases while running an Xcode project.

---

### Prior research of my own

The [language ref for the `DisplayStyle` enum](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Mirror-DisplayStyle_Enumeration/index.html) includes a statement that could possibly describe *that there is* a behaviour as above (however, not *why*)

> A suggestion of how a `Mirror`'s is to be interpreted.
>
> Playgrounds and the debugger will show **a representation similar** to the
>   one used for instances of the kind **indicated by the `DisplayStyle` case name** when the `Mirror` is used for display.

but to be honest, I'm a bit at loss as how to interpret the bold-marked sections above. Possibly this *"similar"* representation could explain the above, but why would Swift want to expose internal (/legacy) names all the way up to the UI (`print(..)`)?

Comment: If you type `Mirror.DisplayStyle.Collection.description` and _cmd-click_ through `description`, you'll find that the PlaygroundLogger module extends `extension DisplayStyle : CustomStringConvertible`. I would say this probably why when you print it will not be the case name. For the reason why they do this, I guess this doesn't matter to us. They might just think `indexContainer` is a better description than `Collection` itself.

Comment: @J.Wang I actually tried to look for a `.description` for these cases, but I cannot reach that PlaygroundLogger module by cmd-clicking at `.description` to any of the cases above; I just get a question mark as response (in addition, compiler error that `.description` does not exist for any of the `DisplayStyle` cases). Even by searching, I cannot find the declaration of such an extension (only the conformance by extension for `Mirror` to `CustomStringConvertible`). It would explain where these `print(..)`:s come from though. Are you running Swift 2.2?

Comment: Yes. I have that module. Make sure you import the `XCPlayground` framework. `import XCPlayground`. `PlaygroundLogger` is part of it.

Comment: @J.Wang Ah I see, there it is, thanks! So the `.description` of the cases of this enum only exists in `XCPlayground`. I wonder if it's really as intended that these legacy names remains as descriptors for the `DisplayStyle` cases?

Comment: well, maybe apple developers just forget to update the description when they change the case names :).

Comment: @J.Wang Possibly, [I filed a rdar just in case](http://www.openradar.me/25540375). Nice catch and localization of the source of this. Feel free to add an answer laying out the details of what we've discussed here, and we can thereafter remove these comments. I you don't feel up to, I'll add a similar answer to close this thread in a day or so. Thanks!